# Find ZEROth Dimension Array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Normally when looking for amount of diensions, or their bounds you can user UBound, and LBound.

I am stuck right now because I have a dynamic array and I want to check if it had its first ReDim ( or if it has at least one dimension).

Without as single dimension UBound( array, 1) is out of  range.

So how do I check if it has zero dimesions?

Result shoud look more or less like this:

```
Dim array()
If NO_DIMENSIONS Then
    ...something...
End if
```

Comment: I thought ubound was -1 in these cases. I normally check if ubound <= 0 to see if an array is populated with anything at all.

Comment: @MattCremeens that is a good idea I ran just now"?UBound(array,-1)" in immediate window but I still got Error "subscript out of range".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use error trapping to accomplish this.

```
Function NumberOfDimensions(arr As Variant)

    'Sets up the error handler.
    On Error GoTo FinalDimension

    'Visual Basic for Applications arrays can have up to 60000
    'dimensions; this allows for that.
    For DimNum = 1 To 60000

        'It is necessary to do something with the LBound to force it
        'to generate an error.
        ErrorCheck = LBound(arr, DimNum)

    Next DimNum

FinalDimension:
        NumberOfDimensions = DimNum - 1

End Function
```

This code was modified into a function from code taken from [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152288).

So you would use as such:

```
Dim testArr()

If NumberOfDimensions(testArr) = 0 Then
    'Do Something
End If
```

In this method, you are taking that subscript out of range error and using it to count how many dimensions there are.